# Azure PostgreSQL does NOT care about certificate?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, azure

My pg flexible server at Azure already has the following SSL parameters set:

[image]
[image]

According to [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/how-to-connect-tls-ssl) it is supposed to reject any request without a valid certificate. But this nodejs connection string from my local VSC F5 always works regardless whether the supplying .pem file exists or not.

```
const conn = "postgres://" + process.env.PGuser 
    +":" + process.env.PGpassword 
    + "@my-pg-flexsvr-test.postgres.database.azure.com/" 
    + process.env.PGdatabase 
    + "?sslmode=verify-all?sslrootcert=./environment/NoSuchFile.crt.pem";
```

Tested with `psql` found:

1. run the default `runpsql.bat` which does not ask for certificate and SSLMode, always works when username/password are correct.
   [image]
2. when providing `sslmode` and `sslrootcert`, they must be valid, for example: `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\scripts>psql "sslmode=verify-full sslrootcert=C:\\Users\\me\\DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt.pem host=my-pg-flexsrv-test.postgres.database.azure.com dbname=mydb user=myuser`

Seems AZ pg doesn't care about your certificate if not supplied or exists.

Local system:

```
VSC: 1.63.1 (system setup)
Date: 2021-12-14T02:13:54.292Z
Electron: 13.5.2
Chromium: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19044
```

Comment: verifying the legitimacy of the server's cert is entirely up to the client.  Whatever is going on here has nothing to do with the database being on Azure specifically.